# Find curve $f$ such that $f(t)+e^sf'(t)$ is immersion, but is not diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Can someone give me just a hint how can I find curve $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$g(s,t)=f(t)+e^s \cdot f'(t)$ is immersion onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ but it is not a diffeomorphism?

I was trying to takie 'random' curves but of course it gave me nothing. How should I looking for such curve?

Answer (score 1):

For a moment suppose that $g$ actually *is* a diffeomorphism. Then the partials of $g$ with respect to $t$ and $s$ must be linearly independent, hence have nonzero cross-product (when you consider the plane as a subset of 3-space). That cross product has only one interesting term -- the $z$-component -- and it turns out to involve a cross-product of $f'(t)$ and $f''(t)$. So...can you think of a curve -- a familiar, simple, curve -- whose velocity and acceleration are non-parallel? (Answer: yes, there are tons of these.)

To be certain that you don't have an actual diffeomorphism, the trick is to be sure that $g$ is not injective. One way to do that is to be sure that $f$ itself is not injective, i.e., that that are values $t_1$ and $t_2 \ne t_1$ with $f(t_1) = f(t_2)$, for then you'll have that $g(t_1, 0) = g(t_2, 0)$, which shows $g$ is not injective.

Surely you can think of a curve $f$ whose velocity and acceleration are always nonzero and non-parallel, and which "intersects" itself in the sense of the previous paragraph...

Comment: Thanks. So circle is a curve whose velocity and acceleration are non-parallel and $f(a)=f(a+2 \pi)$. But I still don't get why such function $g$ must be surjective?

Comment: For a circle, the function's *not* surjective. I missed that part of the original question. (Imagine an ant walking along the circle with a searchlight pointing forward. The image is everyplace that's illuminated). How could you fill in the circle? You could make it smaller...but you'd still miss its interior. What if it got *steadily* smaller, like a spiral? You'd still miss the origin. Try a "folded figure 8" like $f(t) = (cos(2t) - 0.2cos(t), sin(2t) - 0.75sin(t))$ and it *almost* works...the interior of the inner loop is missed. What about an ellipse with an internal loop at each end?

Comment: Thanks. When I read this story about ant I have finally understood what is $f(t)+e^sf'(t)$! I think that two circles with one common point would be ok?

Comment: Two circles, externally tangent, won't work, because at the "crossing" point, the acceleration vector and tangent vector will be parallel. You really need something that looks like an ellipse with an internally tangent circle at each end. I couldn't quickly whip up a plot with internal *tangencies*, but the curve $f(t) = (\cos(3t) + \cos(t), \sin(3t) + 2\sin(t))$ has the "ellipse with an internal loop at each end" shape that's needed. As $t$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$, $g$ covers all of $R^2$ except the upper loop; for $t \in [\pi, 2\pi]$, $g$ covers all of R^2$ except the lower loop. We're done!

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was thinking about curve like (cos(3t)+cos(t),sin(3t)+2sin(t)) for a while (without formula, just picture) but I unfortunately thought about this two circles. Anyway, thank you one more time.